# executing a command after ssh

Tags: ssh

The following command works as expected:

```
ssh soak@10.10.10.11 "ssh soak@10.199.199.191 "mysqlshow""
```

But the following does not:

```
ssh soak@10.10.10.11 "ssh soak@10.199.199.191 "mysql test -Bse"show variables"""
```

The following part works at the command prompt but fails when I do ssh before executing it as shown above.

```
mysql test -Bse"show variables"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't nest double-quotes like that.  You either need to escape them or change your approach.

Try this:

```
ssh soak@10.10.10.11 "ssh soak@10.199.199.191 \"mysql test -Bse'show variables'\""
```

Comment: ssh soak@10.10.10.11 "ssh soak@10.199.199.191 \"mysql test -Bse'show variables'\""

Comment: Ah, yeah, of course you need the outer most quotes too.  I'll fixup my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the command `ssh soak@10.10.10.11 "ssh soak@10.199.199.191 "mysql test -Bse"show variables"""` you have multiple double quotes. Try escaping them

```
ssh soak@10.10.10.11 "ssh soak@10.199.199.191 \"mysql test -Bse\\\"show variables\\\"\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can put

```
mysql test -Bse"show variables"
```

into a script on your server and then just call that script via SSH as you showed in your first example. If you do this, make sure the executable bit is set properly to allow user soak to run it.